# Error al abrir archivo de Excel con PHPEXCEL

Tags: mysql, phpexcel

Buenos días compañeros,

Cordial saludo, recurro nuevamente a su acostumbrada ayuda:

Estoy generando un archivo en Excel de la siguiente manera:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vdn.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"analisis.xlsx\"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');

if ($inventario->num_rows > 0) {
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:B1');//Las celdas A1 a E1 se combinan
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('D1:D2');//Las celdas D1 a D2 se combinan
    
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(40);//Se establece alto de la fila No, 1
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:D1')->getFont()->setSize(20);//Tamaño de letra de la primera fila
    
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:D1')->getFont()->setBold(true);//Negrita para la primera fila
    $sheet->getStyle('A2:D2')->getFont()->setBold(true);//Negrita para la segunda fila
    
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB ('3b83bd');//Color de la letra de la primera fila
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('D1')->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB ('ff0000');//Color de la letra de la segunda fila
    
    //Se centran los titulos
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A1:D1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A1:D1')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A2:B2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A2:B2')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
    
    //Se establecen los bordes de las celdas cabeceras
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:B1')->applyFromArray($styleCells);
    $sheet->getStyle('D1:D2')->applyFromArray($styleCells);
    $sheet->getStyle('A2:B2')->applyFromArray($styleCells);
    
    cellColor($excel,'A2:B2', 'b2b2b2', 0);// Se cambia el color del fondo de las celdas con titulos
    
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'PRODUCTO');//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'INV. TOTAL');//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
    $sheet->setCellValue('A2', 'REFERENCIA');//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
    $sheet->setCellValue('B2', 'DESCRIPCION');//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
    
    //All cells are set as "autosize"
    foreach (range(('A'), ('D')) as $columns){
        $sheet->getColumnDimension($columns)->setAutoSize(true);
    }
    
    $rowSheetT=4;
    $momento_h="";
    while ($row_inventario = $inventario->fetch_assoc()) {
        $categoria = $row_inventario['CATEGORIA_NOMBRE'];
        if ($row_inventario['ARTICULO_CANTIDAD']>0){
            if ($momento_h=="") {
                $sheet->setCellValue('A3', $categoria);//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
                $sheet->getStyle('A3')->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
                $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
                $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A3:B3');//Las celdas A2 a B2 se combinan
                $sheet->getStyle('A3:B3')->applyFromArray($styleCellsthick);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
                $row_inicio = $rowSheetT;
                $nombre_categoria = $categoria;
            }else if($momento_h != intval($row_inventario['ARTICULO_CATEGORIA'])){
                $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT).':J'.($rowSheetT))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
                $sheet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT).':B'.($rowSheetT))->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
                $sheet->getStyle('D'.($rowSheetT))->applyFromArray($styleCellsthick);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
                $sheet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT).':B'.($rowSheetT))->applyFromArray($styleCellsthick);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
                $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A'.($rowSheetT).':B'.($rowSheetT));
                $sheet->setCellValue("A".$rowSheetT,"TOTAL ".$nombre_categoria);
                $sheet->setCellValue("D".$rowSheetT,"=SUM(D".$row_inicio.":D".($rowSheetT-1).")");
                $rowSheetT=$rowSheetT+3;
                $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A'.($rowSheetT).':B'.($rowSheetT));//Las celdas A2 a B2 se combinan
                $sheet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT).':B'.($rowSheetT))->applyFromArray($styleCellsthick);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
                $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT).':B'.($rowSheetT))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
                $sheet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT))->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
                $sheet->setCellValue('A'.($rowSheetT), $categoria);//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
                $rowSheetT++;
                $row_inicio = $rowSheetT;
                $nombre_categoria = $categoria;
            }
            $momento_h = intval($row_inventario['ARTICULO_CATEGORIA']);
            
            $sheet->setCellValue('A'.($rowSheetT), $row_inventario['ARTICULO_REFERENCIA']);// Número de registro en autoincremento
            $sheet->setCellValue('B'.($rowSheetT), $row_inventario['ARTICULO_NOMBRE']);// Número de registro en autoincremento
            $sheet->setCellValue('D'.($rowSheetT), $row_inventario['ARTICULO_CANTIDAD']);// Número de registro en autoincremento
            
            $sheet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT).':B'.($rowSheetT))->applyFromArray($styleCells);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
            $sheet->getStyle('D'.($rowSheetT))->applyFromArray($styleCells);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
            
            $rowSheetT++;
        }
    }
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT).':J'.($rowSheetT))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
    $sheet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT).':J'.($rowSheetT))->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
    $sheet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT).':B'.($rowSheetT))->applyFromArray($styleCellsthick);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
    $sheet->getStyle('D'.($rowSheetT))->applyFromArray($styleCellsthick);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A'.($rowSheetT).':B'.($rowSheetT));
    $sheet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetT))->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
    $sheet->setCellValue('A'.($rowSheetT), 'TOTAL '.$nombre_categoria);//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
    $sheet->setCellValue("A".$rowSheetT,"TOTAL ".$nombre_categoria);
    $sheet->setCellValue("D".$rowSheetT,"=SUM(D".$row_inicio.":D".($rowSheetT-1).")");
}
```

...

```
if ($buscar_categoria->num_rows > 0){//Se encontraron categorias en la BD
    $sheeta = 1;//Se inicia la hoja en 1
    while ($row_buscar_categoria = $buscar_categoria->fetch_assoc()){//Se recorren todos los registros encontrados
        $id_cat = $row_buscar_categoria['REPORTE_REF_CATEGORIA'];//Se obtiene el ID de la categoría
        
        $buscar_nom_cata = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT CATEGORIA_NOMBRE FROM categoria WHERE CATEGORIA_ID='$id_cat'");//Se busca el nombre de la categoria del ID 
        $result_nom_cata = mysqli_fetch_array($buscar_nom_cata);
        $categoria = $result_nom_cata['CATEGORIA_NOMBRE'];//Se obtiene el nombre de la categoria

        $excel->createSheet();//Se crea nueva hoga en el archivo de Excel
        $shet = 'hoja'.$sheeta;
        $shet = $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta);//Se posiciona en la hoja actual
        $shet->setTitle("$categoria");//Se le da nombre a la hoja
        //$rowSheetT=3;
        
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('A1:B1');//Las celdas A1 a B1 se combinan
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('C1:D1');//Las celdas C1 a D1 se combinan
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('E1:J1');//Las celdas E1 a I1 se combinan
        
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->getStyle('A1:J1')->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB ('3b83bd');//Color de la letra de la primera fila
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(40);//Se establece alto de la fila No, 1
            
        $shet->getStyle('A1:J1')->getFont()->setSize(20);//Tamaño de letra de la primera fila
        
        $shet->setCellValue('A1', 'PRODUCTO');//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
        $shet->setCellValue('C1', 'PROMEDIO');//Se establece titulo de la celda C1
        $shet->setCellValue('E1', 'VENTAS '.$ano_actual);//Se establece titulo de la celda C1
        
        $shet->setCellValue('A2', 'REFERENCIA');//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
        $shet->setCellValue('B2', 'DESCRIPCIÓN');//Se establece titulo de la celda B1
        $shet->setCellValue('C2', $ano_actual);//Se establece titulo de la celda C1
        $shet->setCellValue('D2', $anioAnterior);//Se establece titulo de la celda D1
        $shet->setCellValue('E2', strtoupper($monthName));//Se establece titulo de la celda G1
        $shet->setCellValue('F2', strtoupper($monthNameU));//Se establece titulo de la celda G1
        $shet->setCellValue('G2', strtoupper($monthNameD));//Se establece titulo de la celda H1
        $shet->setCellValue('H2', strtoupper($monthNameT));//Se establece titulo de la celda I1
        $shet->setCellValue('I2', strtoupper($monthNameC));//Se establece titulo de la celda J1
        $shet->setCellValue('J2', strtoupper($monthNameCi));//Se establece titulo de la celda J1
                        
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('A1:B1');//Las celdas A2 a B2 se combinan
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('C1:D1');//Las celdas A2 a B2 se combinan
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('E1:J1');//Las celdas A2 a B2 se combinan
        
        $shet->getStyle('A1:J1')->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
        $shet->getStyle('A2:J2')->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
        
        $shet->getStyle('A1:J1')->applyFromArray($styleCells);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
        $shet->getStyle('A2:J2')->applyFromArray($styleCells);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
        
        //El título del informe se centra
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->getStyle('A1:J1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->getStyle('A1:J1')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->getStyle('A2:J2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
        
        cellColor($excel,'A2:J2', 'b2b2b2', $sheeta);// Se cambia el color del fondo de las celdas con titulos
        
        //All cells are set as "autosize"
        foreach (range(('A'), ('J')) as $columnss){
            $shet->getColumnDimension($columnss)->setAutoSize(true);
        }
        
        // Se buscan todos los registros de la tabla
        $buscar_reportes = $link->query("SELECT * FROM reporte_ref WHERE REPORTE_REF_CATEGORIA='$id_cat' ORDER BY REPORTE_REF_SUBCATEGORIA");
        
        if ($buscar_reportes->num_rows > 0){
            $rowSheetTs=4;
            $momento_h="";
            $sum_aactual_prom = 0;
            $sum_apasado_prom = 0;
            $sum_ventas_1 = 0;
            $sum_ventas_2 = 0;
            $sum_ventas_3 = 0;
            $sum_ventas_4 = 0;
            $sum_ventas_5 = 0;
            while ($row_refs = $buscar_reportes->fetch_assoc()){
                $id_subcat = $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_SUBCATEGORIA'];//Se obtiene el ID de la subcategoria
                $buscar_referencia_actual = $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_REFERENCIA'];
                
                $v_p_m_a_a = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT SUM(movimiento_item.CANTIDAD) AS Ventas FROM movimiento_item,movimiento WHERE movimiento.MOVIMIENTO_ID=movimiento_item.MOVIMIENTO_ID AND MOVIMIENTO_TIPO=7 AND MOVIMIENTO_BODEGA=1 AND movimiento_item.ARTICULO_REFERENCIA='$buscar_referencia_actual' AND (YEAR(MOVIMIENTO_FECHA) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(MOVIMIENTO_FECHA) = MONTH(CURDATE()))");
                $result_v_p_m_a_a = mysqli_fetch_array($v_p_m_a_a);
                $ventas_actual = $result_v_p_m_a_a['Ventas'];//Se obtiene el nombre de la subcategoria
                
                $buscar_nom_cata = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT SUBCATEGORIA_NOMBRE FROM subcategoria WHERE SUBCATEGORIA_ID='$id_subcat' AND CATEGORIA_ID='$id_cat'");
                $result_nom_cata = mysqli_fetch_array($buscar_nom_cata);
                $subcategoria = $result_nom_cata['SUBCATEGORIA_NOMBRE'];//Se obtiene el nombre de la subcategoria
                
                if ($momento_h=="") {//Se confirma si es la primera subcategoria.
                    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->getStyle('A3:B3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
                    $shet->getStyle('A3:B3')->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
                    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('A3:B3');//Las celdas A2 a B2 se combinan
                    $shet->setCellValue('A3', $subcategoria);//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
                    $shet->getStyle('A3:B3')->applyFromArray($styleCells);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
                    $row_inicio = $rowSheetTs;
                    $nombre_categoria = $subcategoria;
                }else if($momento_h != intval($row_refs['REPORTE_REF_SUBCATEGORIA'])){// Cuando es más de una subcategoria
                    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':J'.($rowSheetTs))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
                    $shet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':J'.($rowSheetTs))->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
                    $shet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':J'.($rowSheetTs))->applyFromArray($styleCells);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
                    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('A'.($rowSheetTs).':B'.($rowSheetTs));//Se une las celdas A y B
                    $shet->setCellValue("A".$rowSheetTs,"SUBTOTAL ".$nombre_categoria);//Subtotal por subcategoria
                    $shet->setCellValue("C".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(C".$row_inicio.":C".($rowSheetTs-1).")");//Suma Stock en meses
                    $shet->setCellValue("D".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(D".$row_inicio.":D".($rowSheetTs-1).")");//Suma promedio del presente año
                    $shet->setCellValue("E".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(E".$row_inicio.":E".($rowSheetTs-1).")");//Suma promedio del año pasado
                    $shet->setCellValue("F".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(F".$row_inicio.":F".($rowSheetTs-1).")");//Suma stock total
                    $shet->setCellValue("G".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(G".$row_inicio.":G".($rowSheetTs-1).")");
                    $shet->setCellValue("H".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(H".$row_inicio.":H".($rowSheetTs-1).")");
                    $shet->setCellValue("I".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(I".$row_inicio.":I".($rowSheetTs-1).")");
                    $shet->setCellValue("J".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(J".$row_inicio.":J".($rowSheetTs-1).")");
                    $rowSheetTs=$rowSheetTs+2;
                    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('A'.($rowSheetTs).':B'.($rowSheetTs));//Las celdas A2 a B2 se combinan
                    $shet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':B'.($rowSheetTs))->applyFromArray($styleCells);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
                    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':B'.($rowSheetTs))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
                    $shet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs))->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
                    $shet->setCellValue('A'.($rowSheetTs), $subcategoria);//Se establece titulo de la celda A1
                    $rowSheetTs++;
                    $row_inicio = $rowSheetTs;
                    $nombre_categoria = $subcategoria;
                }
                $momento_h = intval($row_refs['REPORTE_REF_SUBCATEGORIA']);
                
                $shet->setCellValue('A'.($rowSheetTs), $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_REFERENCIA']);// Referencia del artículo
                $shet->setCellValue('B'.($rowSheetTs), $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_DESCRIPCION']);// Descripción del artículo
                $shet->setCellValue('C'.($rowSheetTs), $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_PROM_ACTUAL']);// Promedio de ventas año actual
                $shet->setCellValue('D'.($rowSheetTs), $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_PROM_PASADO']);// Promedio de ventas año pasado
                $shet->setCellValue('E'.($rowSheetTs), $ventas_actual);// Ventas del mes en curso
                $shet->setCellValue('F'.($rowSheetTs), $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_1_MES_ACTUAL']);// Ventas del mes pasado
                $shet->setCellValue('G'.($rowSheetTs), $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_2_MES_ACTUAL']);// Ventas de hace dos meses
                $shet->setCellValue('H'.($rowSheetTs), $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_3_MES_ACTUAL']);// Ventas de hace tres meses
                $shet->setCellValue('I'.($rowSheetTs), $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_4_MES_ACTUAL']);// Ventas de hace cuatro meses
                $shet->setCellValue('J'.($rowSheetTs), $row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_5_MES_ACTUAL']);// Ventas de hace cinco meses
                $sum_aactual_prom = $sum_aactual_prom+$row_refs['REPORTE_REF_PROM_ACTUAL'];//Total de promedio del año presente
                $sum_apasado_prom = $sum_apasado_prom+$row_refs['REPORTE_REF_PROM_PASADO'];//Total de promedio del año pasado
                $sum_ventas_1 = $sum_ventas_1+$row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_1_MES_ACTUAL'];//Total de ventas del mes pasado
                $sum_ventas_2 = $sum_ventas_2+$row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_2_MES_ACTUAL'];//Total de ventas de hace dos meses
                $sum_ventas_3 = $sum_ventas_3+$row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_3_MES_ACTUAL'];//Total de ventas de hace tres meses
                $sum_ventas_4 = $sum_ventas_4+$row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_4_MES_ACTUAL'];//Total de ventas de hace cuatro meses
                $sum_ventas_5 = $sum_ventas_5+$row_refs['REPORTE_REF_VENTAS_5_MES_ACTUAL'];//Total de ventas de hace cinco meses
                
                $rowSheetTs++;
            }
            $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':J'.($rowSheetTs))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
            $shet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':J'.($rowSheetTs))->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
            $shet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':J'.($rowSheetTs))->applyFromArray($styleCells);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
            $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('A'.($rowSheetTs).':B'.($rowSheetTs));//Se une las celdas A y B
            $shet->setCellValue("A".$rowSheetTs,"SUBTOTAL ".$nombre_categoria);//Subtotal por subcategoria
            $shet->setCellValue("C".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(C".$row_inicio.":C".($rowSheetTs-1).")");//Suma Stock en meses
            $shet->setCellValue("D".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(D".$row_inicio.":D".($rowSheetTs-1).")");//Suma promedio del presente año
            $shet->setCellValue("E".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(E".$row_inicio.":E".($rowSheetTs-1).")");//Suma promedio del año pasado
            $shet->setCellValue("F".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(F".$row_inicio.":F".($rowSheetTs-1).")");//Suma stock total
            $shet->setCellValue("G".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(G".$row_inicio.":G".($rowSheetTs-1).")");
            $shet->setCellValue("H".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(H".$row_inicio.":H".($rowSheetTs-1).")");
            $shet->setCellValue("I".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(I".$row_inicio.":I".($rowSheetTs-1).")");
            $shet->setCellValue("J".$rowSheetTs,"=SUM(J".$row_inicio.":J".($rowSheetTs-1).")");
            $rowSheetTs+=3;
            $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->mergeCells('A'.($rowSheetTs).':B'.($rowSheetTs));//Las celdas A2 a B2 se combinan
            $shet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':J'.($rowSheetTs))->applyFromArray($styleCells);//Se aplica los bordes de la primera fila
            $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheeta)->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':J'.($rowSheetTs))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
            $shet->getStyle('A'.($rowSheetTs).':J'.($rowSheetTs))->getFont()->setBold(true);//Se establece en Negrita los titulos
            $shet->setCellValue('A'.($rowSheetTs), 'TOTAL '.$categoria);//Titulo de TOTAL de todos las celdas
            $shet->setCellValue('C'.($rowSheetTs), $sum_aactual_prom);//Suma total de stock en meses
            $shet->setCellValue('D'.($rowSheetTs), $sum_apasado_prom);//Suma total del promedio del año actual
            $shet->setCellValue('E'.($rowSheetTs), $ventas_actual);//Suma total de las ventas del mes pasado
            $shet->setCellValue('F'.($rowSheetTs), $sum_ventas_1);//Suma total de las ventas de hace dos meses
            $shet->setCellValue('G'.($rowSheetTs), $sum_ventas_2);//Suma total de las ventas de hace tres meses
            $shet->setCellValue('H'.($rowSheetTs), $sum_ventas_3);//Suma total de las ventas de hace cuatro meses
            $shet->setCellValue('I'.($rowSheetTs), $sum_ventas_4);//Suma total de las ventas de hace cinco meses
            $shet->setCellValue('I'.($rowSheetTs), $sum_ventas_5);//Suma total de las ventas de hace cinco meses
        }
        $sheeta++;
    }
    
}

$nombre_archivo = strtoupper($monthName).'_'.$dia_actual.'_'.$ano_actual;
$url = "inventario/analisis/miami/".$nombre_archivo.".xlsx";// Se busca el archivo de excel en el servidor
fclose(__DIR__."/inventario/analisis/miami/".$nombre_archivo.".xlsx");//Se cierra archivo
unlink("inventario/analisis/miami/".$nombre_archivo.".xlsx");//Se elimina archivo del servidor
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007');// Se genera el Excel
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save(__DIR__."/inventario/analisis/miami/".$nombre_archivo.".xlsx");// Se guarda el Excel en el servidor
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($nombre_archivo));
readfile($nombre_archivo);
```

Cuando reviso veo que se genera el archivo pero al tratar de abrirlo y/o enviarlo por correo me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle en si me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado investigando y encontré las siguientes sugerencias:
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Past_Due_Report.xls"");
ob_implicit_flu`introducir el código aquí`sh(1);
ob_clean();
Pero ninguna de esas sugerencias me ha funcionado...

No sé que pueda estar haciendo mal... Su ayuda por favor

Comment: Compañeros, después de revisar y revisar encontré que genera la falla en la línea: $shetes = $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetass);//Se posiciona en la hoja actual.   La variable $sheetass la inicializó en 1 y que vaya creando las hojas de acuerdo a los registros encontrados.  Alguno tiene idea de que puede estar pasando?}

Comment: Compañeros su ayuda... no he podido detectar el error: Ya encontré que es con la variable: $hoja = 1;//Se inicia la hoja en 1; $excel->createSheet();//Se crea nueva hoga en el archivo de Excel; $hojas = $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($hoja);//Se posiciona en la hoja actual
   $hojas->setTitle("$categoria");//Se le da nombre a la hoja. Cuando quito la variable $hoja si funciona pero no me genera el reporte correctamente y al finalizar el while lo incremento en 1: $hoja++;.